# setContent leads to i18n problem at NextJs

Tags: puppeteer, next.js13, i18next

I'm working on converting a web page into a PDF format. To achieve this, I've set up a Next.js API backend endpoint. This endpoint is supposed to utilize the setContent function to render my React component, which will then be converted into the desired PDF.

However, I've encountered an issue: Puppeteer is unable to render the React component due to the absence of its i18n configuration.

Below is a brief example:

API-endpoint:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next/types';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { handleApiError } from 'src/errors/general';
import { InvalidRequestTypeError } from 'src/errors/validation';
import fs from 'fs'; // Importieren des File System Moduls
import { MyComponent } from 'src/components/my-component';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import '../../i18n';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

    try {
        if (req.method !== 'GET') {
            throw new InvalidRequestTypeError('Invalid request method');
        }
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const propsForComponent = {
            /* Ihre Props hier */
        };
        const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <MyComponent />,
        );
        await page.setContent(htmlString);
        const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
        const outputPath = './output.pdf'; // Sie können den Dateinamen und den Pfad ändern
        fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, pdfBuffer);
        res.status(200).json({});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        handleApiError(error, res);
    }
}
```

../../i18n:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    backend: {
        loadPath: 'public/locales/de/default.json', // Pfad zu Ihren Übersetzungsdateien
    },
    lng: 'de', // Sie können die Standardsprache hier festlegen
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    defaultNS: 'default',
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

```bash
react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next
```

Has somebody an idea?

T